# Angular - why does Validators.pattern do nothing in prod but works on my local dev?

Tags: javascript, html, angular

Angular - why does Validators.pattern do nothing in prod but works on my local dev?

I added Validators.pattern and '*ngIf="email.errors.pattern"' to an already existing form doing client side validation on email. This all works in development mode, I see the alert if I input an email that violates the pattern. However, when building a dist folder and migrating it to production this new client side check does nothing in the prod environment.

my-add-user-component.ts

```
  email: new FormControl(this.user.email, [
    Validators.required,
    Validators.email,
    Validators.maxLength(50),
    Validators.pattern("(?!.*[\\+|#|$|%|^|\\*|\\?]).*")
  ]),
```

my-add-user.html

```
        <div *ngIf="email.invalid && (email.dirty || email.touched)" class="alert alert-danger">
            <div *ngIf="email.errors.required">
                Email is required
            </div>
            <div *ngIf="email.errors.maxlength">
                Email cannot exceed 50 characters
            </div>
            <div *ngIf="email.errors.email">
                Email is invalid
            </div>
            <div *ngIf="email.errors.pattern">
                Special characters not allowed in email
            </div>
            <div *ngIf="email.errors.duplicateEmail">
                Email already exists
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer - Clear Browser Cache. Even though I have startup settings in Chrome, I still get bit. For some reason, I still have to clear the cache manually at times.